# Best way to track changes and make changes from Mysql -> MSSQL

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql-server, vbulletin

So I need to track changes that happen on a Mysql table. I was thinking of using triggers to log all the changes made to it and then save these changes in another table. Then I will have a cron script get all these changes and propagate the changes into the Mssql database.

I really dont expect a lot of information to be proporgated, but the data is very time sensitive. Ideally the MSSQL will see these changes within a minute, but I know that this requirement may be too high.

I was wondering if anyone had a better solution.

I have the bulk of the site written in .net but use vbulletin as the forums (sorry but there are no .net forums as powerful or feature rich like vbulletin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of the replicator tools use this technique. Fill another table on insert/update/delete triggers that containt the tablename and the PK or a unique key.

Then a reader reads this table, do the proper "select" if insert/update to get the data, then updates the other database.

HTH

Comment: I'm tempted to give credit for the answer, but I really was hoping for more answers. I wanted to see some sort of discussion.

Comment: Well, see that way: nobody could find a better answer than mine! ;-)